# How to add custom layout handles programatically for Category View in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, update-handle

So, I want to add a custom layout handle for all category view pages.. the handle that is supposed to be loaded depends on certain category parameters, so the handle needs to be added programmatically with `$page->addPageLayoutHandles()`

Seems easy..? Apparently not

Magento 2 provides a nice Plugin system that I was naturally going to use, just define a `afterExecute()` plugin to be run after the original category `execute()` and push any updates into the Page object from there.

Unfortunately, it does not quite work that way.. reason being that the original `execute()` method (at the very end) will execute `$page->getConfig()->addBodyClass()` -- a call to this method will automatically force the layout to be completely loaded and generated, so any subsequent attempts to add new layout handles to Page are completely useless.
I looked around to find any not-so-elegant-ways to achieve the same thing (still using plugins).. did not find any.

I ended up running my own controller for category view, however, I would not prefer to leave it that way.

So my question is.. **how can I add new page layout handles (programmatically) for category view? and do it elegantly.**

Comment: What Magento version are you using? Because where can you see that `$page->getConfig()->addBodyClass()` loads and generates your layout? I'm having a similar task at the moment, only with CMS pages.

Comment: I am so glad you noted this, as you saved me a bunch of grief. Just FYI: the category view controller also calls the $page->getConfig()->addBodyClass() which makes a plugin useless for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 17):

### The XML way

Well an easy way is to create the following file in your module folder: `view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="your_custom_handle"/>
</page>
```

It is not more or less elegant than the PHP way and according to what you found it is safer.

### The PHP way

Unfortunately in your case, it seems like PHP is the only way to achieve dynamically create handles based on the parameters the category has.

### Via plugins

Instead of creating a plugin on the `execute()` method of your action class, you could directly create a plugin on the `addPageLayoutHandles()` method of `Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page`

**Main problem is that it will be called every time this method is called and you will have to add some conditions in your plugin code to ensure you're on a category view page.**

### Via preferences

Another way of doing it would be to use preferences for the category view action class:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View"
                type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Category\View"/>
</config>
```

Then in your custom controller class you simply override the `execute()` method by copying/pasting the original method and add your modifications directly in this method.

**Main problem is that when you will upgrade your Magento install, if changes are added to the original native Magento action class, it won't reflect in your custom action class.**

Comment: The issue is.. it needs to be programatically added. Simply because the handle being loaded depends on the parameters that the category has.

Comment: @KristjanH. hmmm I see it's embarassing, let me dig further

Comment: @KristjanH. see my update

Comment: Using <preference>.. that is, what I did just before I wrote the question here, however, I'm not happy with that. Same with using a plugin on addPageLayoutHandles, I don't want to call a plugin all the time, even if the performance penalty is non-existent, it's just not right. Let's see if any other solutions appear here.

Comment: Did you try any other way after this?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem. for categories that do not show product listings I needed an extra handle. after [failing to add the handle](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5901) through the category's Custom Layout XML, I ended up adding it in an observer on the `layout_load_before` event:

```
class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * add a custom handle to categories of page type 'PAGE'
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getData('full_action_name');
        if ($action != 'catalog_category_view')
            return $this;

        $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        if (!$category)
            return $this;

        if ($category->getDisplayMode() == $category::DM_PAGE) {
            $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_category_view_cms');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

there is a small performance hit involved as the observer is called for every pageview. unfortunately, all 'category_view' related events seem either too early (category not yet loaded) or too late (layout already processed).

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar problem (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156231/magento-2-how-can-i-add-customer-dashboard-navigation-programatically) and a plugin on `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View::execute()` and `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page::addPageLayoutHandles() or render()` didn't do the trick. This last-resort solution was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try observing event layout_load_before. Execute function will be as same as this:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if($observer->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view'){
            $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('your_custom_handles');
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help