# Magento 2 : How can I add customer dashboard navigation programatically

Tags: magento2, cms, plugin, dashboard

Let's talk abstract: I have a certain parameter which determines wether or not the customer account dashboard navigation should be shown on a page or not.

My CMS page has the layout '2 columns left' and I use a plugin/interceptor to try to manipulate the layout.

In short, when I add a `cms_page_view.xml` to my module, and add the following, the navigation is shown:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account" />
</page>
```

Of course, this will add the customer dashboard navigation to all CMS pages, and I only want this to be visible on some pages. So currently I'm using a plugin to wrap around the `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View::execute()`-method:

```
public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View $subject, callable $proceed)
{
    $pageId = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('page_id', $subject->getRequest()->getParam('id', false));

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $proceed();

    // Some code that determines whether or not this CMS page should have the dashboard navigation:
    if ( ... ) {
        // Add customer_account layout update:
        // This is the part that doesn't work...
        $resultPage->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate('customer_account');
    }

    return $resultPage;
}
```

Why doesn't this work and how can I make it work? An interesting sidenote is that if I add a layout update in the admin with the following:

```
<update handle="customer_account" />
```

It also doesn't work. Any thoughts on this matter anyone? I'm using Magento 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in [this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128214/2030).

I ended up by creating an event that listens to `layout_load_before` and inject my layout update in the observer:

```
class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * LayoutLoadBefore constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getData('full_action_name');

        if ($action != 'cms_page_view') {
            return $this;
        }

        $pageId = $this->request->getParam('page_id', $this->request->getParam('id', false));

        // Method that checks if $pageId needs to have the customer_account layout update:
        if (...) {
            $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_account');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone. I've already spent way too much time on this one! ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It helps a lot indeed :) I just would like to give the current CMS page, which is a custom link in the customer menu, the "active" state in the menu itself. Do you know how to achieve that?